# Android: How to set clickable areas of a single image?

Tags: android, image

I want to create a scrollable map and trigger different actions when the user touches a different areas.

With iPhone, it was easy by putting buttons on top of the image. How do I do it in Android?

I used a custom view to enable scrolling in both directions. Now how do I make different parts of the image trigger different events on click?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [clickable area of image](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16670774/clickable-area-of-image)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some idea: You could try to use some ImageButtons. Just chop your picture in four parts. See: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageButton.html

Comment: Yes, I had tried that. But then problem is that I wont be able to set it as a scrollable image.