# clickable area of image

Tags: android, onclicklistener, imagemap

i'am designing a GUI remote control, but instead of making separate buttons for each remote button, i want to get a full ready remote image and set certain parts of it click-able.
is there a way rather than the motion event to do this?

Comment: You want to make it all in one image?

Comment: is their a way to somehow split an image to rows and columns?

Comment: @OutflorksUsus: would you mind if whole image stays clickable but you can surely get precise information of which area has been clicked?

Comment: @MehulJoisar if this doesn't make false actions when the application runs then no problem

Comment: i thought of using gridview layout but i couldn't set a back ground image for it

Comment: @OutflorksUsus:ok,let me write an answer for your requirement.

Comment: I think you should use motion event for this.

Answer (score 43):

I have 2 solutions for your requirement.in both,the whole image stays clickable but you can get information about clicked area.

**Solution 1:**

you can mask the image and get the pixel **color** of that underneath image.so ultimately you can come to know which area has been clicked.

here,whenever clicked occurs,you can check the pixel color of `background image` and match it with predefined color set to know about which area has been clicked.

Foreground image:
[image: Foreground image]

Background image:
[image: Background image]

Clickable area:
[image: Representing clickable area]

Still confused?

**Reference:**
I would like to suggest you to go through [this](http://blahti.wordpress.com/2012/06/26/images-with-clickable-areas/) tutorial.

**Solution 2:**

you can map your image with **co-ordinates** and accordingly you can get the information of area which has been clicked.

Example:
**MappedImage with co-ordinates**

if you are not aware of co-ordinates,you can create your mappedimage from [here](http://www.image-maps.com)

co-ordinates for Kansas will look something like this,

```
        <area shape="poly" coords="243,162,318,162,325,172,325,196,244,196" id="@+id/area14" name = "Kansas"/>
```

[image: MappedImage with co-ordinates]

**Reference:**
Please have a look at [Android Image Mapping](https://github.com/catchthecows/AndroidImageMap).

I hope it will be helpful !!

Comment: Thanks for this! Any idea how to use any of these methods in a titanium alloy app?

Comment: What if we have to zoom the image and get pixel? Does it return same color?

Answer (score 8):

You can still use buttons.

You can place them over your image in the correct spots and make them invisible.

In XML

```
<Button android:visibility="invisible"/>
```

Or

```
Button mybutton = (Button) v1;
mybutton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
```

Comment: I have a relative layout with some buttons in it. If I set a background image on the relative layout and the buttons to invisible, then the onClick doesn't get triggered. When I set them to visible, they do.

Comment: Wouldn't this depend on how you are making your buttons invisible? I.e., if you are setting the `visibility` attribute to `gone` (or `invisible`) then they can't be clicked, but what if you tried making the background of the button 100% transparent - I expect you would still get a click event(??)

Comment: @sealz I like this solution but visibility didn't work. I made the background transparent and it worked.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same challenges and solved it with the library ["PhotoView"](https://github.com/chrisbanes/PhotoView), where you can listen for

```
onPhotoTap(View view, float x, float y){}
```

events and check if the tab is inside your image area, and then perform certain tasks.

I created a library to to help other developers implement such functionality much faster. It's on Github: [ClickableAreasImages](https://github.com/Lukle/ClickableAreasImages)

This library lets you define clickable areas in an image, associate objects to it and listen for touch events on that area.

How To Use the library:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnClickableAreaClickedListener {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Add image
        ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        image.setImageResource(R.drawable.simpsons);

        // Create your image
        ClickableAreasImage clickableAreasImage = new ClickableAreasImage(new PhotoViewAttacher(image), this);

        // Initialize your clickable area list
        List<ClickableArea> clickableAreas = new ArrayList<>();

        // Define your clickable areas
        // parameter values (pixels): (x coordinate, y coordinate, width, height) and assign an object to it
        clickableAreas.add(new ClickableArea(500, 200, 125, 200, new Character("Homer", "Simpson")));
        clickableAreas.add(new ClickableArea(600, 440, 130, 160, new Character("Bart", "Simpson")));
    }

    // Listen for touches on your images:
    @Override
    public void onClickableAreaTouched(Object item) {
        if (item instanceof Character) {
            String text = ((Character) item).getFirstName() + " " + ((Character) item).getLastName();
            Toast.makeText(this, text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
...
}
```

Comment: What if I need to check for clicks in non rectangular shaped areas, like circles? Does it work with your library? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If clicking rectangles is enough, then this can be achieved quite easily by extending ImageView. The following is a simple implementation, without regard to accessibility.

The View:

```
package com.example.letzterwille.views;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Rect;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.widget.ImageView;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import androidx.annotation.Nullable;

public class ClickableAreaImageView extends ImageView {

    Map< Rect, Runnable > areaEffects = new HashMap<>();

    public ClickableAreaImageView( Context context ) {
        super( context );
    }

    public ClickableAreaImageView( Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs ) {
        super( context, attrs );
    }

    public ClickableAreaImageView( Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr ) {
        super( context, attrs, defStyleAttr );
    }

    public ClickableAreaImageView( Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes ) {
        super( context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes );
    }

    public void addAreaEffect( Rect target, Runnable event ) {
        areaEffects.put( target, event );
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent( MotionEvent event ) {
        if ( event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN ) {
            int x = ( int ) event.getX();
            int y = ( int ) event.getY();

            for ( Map.Entry< Rect, Runnable > entry : areaEffects.entrySet() ) {
                Rect rect = entry.getKey();
                if ( rect.contains( x, y ) ) entry.getValue().run();
            }
        }

        return super.onTouchEvent( event );
    }
}
```

In your XML or Java, use it like a normal ImageView.

Then, you have to register the click actions. I wanted to go to specific activities, which looked like this in Kotlin:

```
class MenuSelection : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_menu_selection)
        val areaImage = findViewById<ClickableAreaImageView>(R.id.menuSelectionImage)

        areaImage.addAreaEffect(Rect(530, 100, 1080, 800), makeRunnable(SettingsActivity::class.java))
        areaImage.addAreaEffect(Rect(30, 80, 430, 700), makeRunnable(StatsActivity::class.java))
    }

    private fun makeRunnable(activity: Class<*>): Runnable {
        return Runnable {
            val intent = Intent(this, activity)
            startActivity(intent)
            overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_from_bottom, R.anim.slide_out_to_top);
        }
    }
}
```

In general, use it by defining rectangles, a Runnable to execute when the rectangle is clicked and then add them to the view via `ClickableAreaImageView.addAreaEffect`

Comment: Great example. Thanks. why mix java and kotlin. It makes it more complicated than necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Improving @sealz reply, here my answer:

```
<RelativeLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    >
    <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/mail"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/mail"
        >
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/leftMail"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight=".5"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/rightMail"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight=".5"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"    
            />
        </LinearLayout>
    <ImageView 
       android:id="@+id/mail"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/mail1600x600"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        />
</RelativeLayout>
```