# Clickable resizable buttons on image android

Tags: android, image, clickable-image

I am trying to create an application which has a map image in it.

I want to add some areas (or buttons) to it so that when you click them the bubbles with information will appear.

I am new in android programming so asking to explain a bit how to implement it?
Also i need an image to be re-sizable just like a real map.

So should i attach the buttons to specific places on image and how to do so that the buttons will be connected to it when i re-size an image?

Which image type is better to use for this purpose? I heard that SVG would be better but i couldn't even add svg image to an application.

I appreciate any helpful advice.

Comment: I dont mean this in a bad way, but please, read http://developer.android.com/training/index.html. You still have long way to go.

Comment: have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16670774/clickable-area-of-image/16671342#16671342)

Comment: It's not resizable. I know how to make it clickable, but how to make it both clickable and resizable?

Answer (score 0):

For your problem you can use this:
http://catchthecows.com/?p=113

I need something similar, but the click on the image should change the content of that part as well.
When I find or implement the final solution I can post it here.