# Android game Menu clickable

Tags: java, android, graphics

Hello everyone I am looking for some advice, I am currently making my game and for the game menu I was thinking to do something like this 
[menu inspiration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WevnH.png)

For the buttons like play option and stuff how do I make them clickable?

Comment: Hello and welcome. Please spend some time reading http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: which framework/Lib are you using in Android for game?

Comment: I'm not using any framework or library it's a board game

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your using Buttons you should add a Listener like this:

```
yourButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            //your code
        }

    });
    return true;
}
```

Hope that helps!

**EDIT:**

Found a little example here: http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/core/view/onclicklistener/android-onclicklistener-example/

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but how I make that section of the image clickable

Comment: @mrJoker you could add a transparent ui-element(like a button) over it and do it with the onClickListener. That is a little workaround I will think about another way....

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16670774/clickable-area-of-image is this what you need?

Answer (score 1):

You may situate your **button** as you want, and use in your xml layout this attribute: `android:visibility="invisible"`

In code you set `onClickListener()` on this invisible button:

```
yourMenuButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                // your code
            }
        });
```