# Android - create clickable area on imageview

Tags: android, image, mapping, area, clickable

I want to create a clickable area on imageview using this data

```
"X1": "213",
"Y1": "174",
"X2": "339",
"Y2": "269",
```

and also I want to associate a Action with this clickable area like go to some Activity when tap on it.
I don't want to use solution given in this link.
[clickable area of image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16670774/clickable-area-of-image)

Because I have multiple Imageviews and coordinates can be different every time. These ordinates are coming from server.

please suggest the best way to handle this problem.

Comment: You can create RectF object with provided coordinates and use onTouchListner to imageview and compare your rectf with clicked area.

Comment: You could try to use Rectangles (`Rect()`), a `onTouchListener()` for the whole layout, and check if the event coordinates are within your rectangle. There is also a Layout called [`AbsoluteLayout`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsoluteLayout.html), where you can specify exact locations, which I do not recommend, since you don't support different screen sizes if you use it.

Comment: Will Rectangles (Rect()) also scale my given ordinates according to the screen size? as my imageview is match_parent in width and wrap_content in height?

Comment: because Server is giving these ordinates for a image  with width 640px and height 380px.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can watch the touched locations:

```
ImageView iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);
iv.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    log.d(TAG,"Location: " + event.getX() + " , " + event.getY());
    }
});
```

**UPDATE 1:**
You can have the top-left location of your view as follow:

```
int[] viewCoords = new int[2];
imageView.getLocationOnScreen(viewCoords);
```

From there, you can see the exact location of your image view that get touched:

```
int X = (int) event.getX();
int Y = (int) event.getY();

int imageX = X - viewCoords[0];
int imageY = Y - viewCoords[1];
```

Comment: For this I guess first i need to scale my image for new screen size and then also scale my coordinates for new screen width and only then I can use this Listener. Am i right sir?

Comment: let me try this solution and than i'll get back to you.

Comment: Thanks buddy. I have converted imageX and ImageY from PX  to Dp and now I think I am almost near to my solution. Again Thanks a lot.

Comment: Perfect. I'm glad to hear that.

Comment: @HamzaMehmood It will be great if you can post complete solution which you have implemented.