# Detecting RGB of pixel tapped in Flutter Dart app

Tags: dart, flutter, imagemap

I'm developing my first application in Flutter.

It mainly consists in an image with different areas and the goal is to detect the tap on different areas.

The solution I'm going to use is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16670774/clickable-area-of-image).
The problem is that I didn't find the method to retrieve the RGB of the tapped pixel. The only detail I have after the Tap event is the position. See [TapUpDetails](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/gestures/TapUpDetails-class.html).

Am I wrong? If not, do you have solutions to suggest?

Thank you