# Android Irregular clickable buttons

Tags: android, button, android-drawable, radial

**My Problem is Overlapping Buttons (Only Transparent Region overlaps).**

[image: Transparent Region Overlapping]

**Can we make only the visible part of an image/drawable Clickable? (Ignoring Transparent (alpha channel) of the button?**

(I am a designer, designing GUI)

Comment: you have a single image ?

Comment: No, i will deliver each clickable image separately.

Comment: it is possible to make only the visible part of an image/drawable Clickable but requires time and effort.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [clickable area of image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16670774/clickable-area-of-image)

Comment: @GastónSaillén Close Enough! but it lacks Overlapping buttons of Transparent Region.

Answer (score 0):

It is quite difficult to achieve but you can ask developer to do a POC with [this library](https://github.com/Lukle/ClickableAreasImages)