# Implement multiple clicks on an imageview

Tags: android

I want to implement multiple clicks on an [Image View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/00IvR.png). The image view consists of a `Map` which has multiple slots

EG:-
The Image consists apart of the `Image View`

Comment: use onTouch listener to check which pixel has been touched, and therefore - determine which part of image was clicked

Comment: Thanks for your assistance. I want to allow the users to select a particular slot from the map.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [clickable area of image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16670774/clickable-area-of-image)