# Is there a way in android to define an on click for a vector path

Tags: java, android, button, view

In Android, I am trying to create a controller that has buttons near the joystick. The buttons themselves are adjacent to the joystick itself and don't have a standard geometry. 
Here is a photo of what I am trying to create:

[joystick](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BIyN6.png)

I know there are ways of hacking this, but I want to see if I can find a more elegant solution to creating a custom area that is clickable and not the bounding box from some geometry.

I took a look around and found some stuff from around 6-7 years ago and I don't know if there is a better solution out there. 
[Example](https://blahti.wordpress.com/2012/06/26/images-with-clickable-areas/)

In the end, I expect the geometry of the button to match the area in which in can be clickable.

Comment: Have you looked at Solution 2 of https://stackoverflow.com/a/16671342/423105 (using AndroidImageMap)?

Comment: Yes, I did I actually looked at the GitHub repository for quite some time. It's from quite a long time ago and I was hoping there was a more modern solution. If push comes to shove I am going to do it that way.